# Why is $Tr_R(T_a\{T_bT_c\})=-Tr_\overline{R}(T_a\{T_bT_c\})$ for $SU(N)$ representations?

Tags: gauge-theory, representation-theory, lie-algebra, yang-mills, quantum-anomalies

I'm looking at the chiral anomaly in QFT and the term
$$d_{abc}=Tr_R(T_a\{T_b,T_c\})$$
shows up where $Tr_R$ means the trace in the representation $R$, $\overline{R}$ is the conjugate representation and $T_a$ are the lie algebra generators.

I've seen it stated in a number of sources that for real and pseudoreal representations $d_{abc}$ vanishes, and I think this is because
$$Tr_R(T_a\{T_bT_c\})=-Tr_\overline{R}(T_a\{T_bT_c\}).$$

From this the result follows since real and pseudoreal representations are equivalent to their conjugate.

I'm not sure why the above equation holds. I can prove it if I assume the representations of the $T_a$ are anti-hermitian (in my convention, the $T_a$ are anti-hermitian). But I don't see why elements of a lie algebra being anti-hermitian should imply that their representations must be too.

**Edit:**

Prahar in the comments pointed out that the conjugate representation has $(T_a)_\overline{R}=-(T_a^*)_R$. I had missed this minus sign in my definitions. With this in mind, I think for my attemped proof I would actually need the $(T_a)_R$ hermitian (which confuses me more since in the fundamental representation of $su(2)$ they are anti-hermitian).

My attempted proof is as follows:

$$
Tr_\overline{R}(T_a\{T_b,T_c\})=-Tr_R(T_a^*\{T_b^*,T_c^*\})=-Tr_R(\{T_b^\dagger,T_c^\dagger\}T_a^\dagger)=-Tr_R(T_a^\dagger\{T_b^\dagger,T_c^\dagger\})
$$

so if the $(T_a)_R$ are hermitian then the result follows.

Comment: In a Hermitian basis $(T^a)^\dagger = T^a$. The generators in the conjugate rep are ${\bar T}^a = - (T^a)^* = - (T^a)^T$.

Comment: @Prahar I had missed the minus sign in this definition before. In this case I think I need the $T_a$ to be Hermitian. I'll edit the question to reflect this.

Comment: For anti-Hermitian generators you have $(T^a)^\dagger = - T^a$. The conjugate rep is then given by ${\bar T}^a = (T^a)^* = - (T^a)^T$. Then everything should simply follow.

Comment: @Prahar I'm very likely misunderstanding something here, but my confusion is about how $T_a^\dagger$ relates to $(T_a)_R^\dagger$. I know that $T_a^\dagger=-T_a$, but I don't know what this says about $(T_a)_R$.

Comment: To be clear I'm using $T_a$ to refer to the Lie Algebra element and $(T_a)_R$ to refer to its image under the representation.

Comment: It says the same thing. Anti-hermiticity implies $(T^a)_R^\dagger = - (T^a)_R$. The conjugate representation is always given by $(T^a)_{\bar R} = - (T^a)^T_R$ (whether or not the generators or Hermitian or anti-Hermitian).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/145612/discussion-between-acernine-and-prahar).

Answer (score 1):

The following is the solution I came to with help from Prahar in the comments.

There are two important points here. First is the definition of the conjugate representation, and the second is the class of representations we are considering.

The conjugate representation is defined as the complex conjugate on the *group* representation, not the lie algebra representation. Explicitly, for a group element $g=\exp(X)$ where $X$ is the corresponding lie algebra element, and representation $\rho$ with conjugate $\overline{\rho}$ we have
$$\overline{\rho}(g)=\rho(g)^*$$
but in QFT we are only considering *unitary* group representations, meaning
$$\rho(g)^*=\rho(g)^{-T}$$
so in terms of the lie algebra we have
$$\exp(\overline{\rho}(X))=\overline{\rho}(g)=\rho(g)^{-T}=\exp(\rho(X))^{-T}=\exp(-\rho(X)^T)$$
so the conjugate representation on the lie algebra is
$$\overline{\rho}=-\rho(X)^T.$$

With this in mind, the relation
$$Tr(\rho(T_a)\{\rho(T_b),\rho(T_c)\})=-Tr(\overline{\rho}(T_a)\{\overline{\rho}(T_b),\overline{\rho}(T_c)\})$$
follows immediately from the general identity
$$Tr(A)=Tr(A^T).$$

Real and pseudoreal representations are equivalent to their conjugates, so for these representations $d_{abc}$ must vanish.